# Connecting to a database using python and running it as a cron job

Tags: python

I have a couple of python scripts which I plan to put up on a server and run them repeatedly once a day. This python script does some calculation and finally uploads the data to a central database. Of course to connect to the database a password and username is required. Is it safe to input this username and password on my python script. If not is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Depends on your permissions and security settings.

Comment: I am using shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DB user with limited access rights, for example, to that only table where it uploads data to. Hardcode that user in your script or pass it as command line arguments. There is little else you can do for a automated script because it has to use some username and password to connect to the DB somehow.

You could encrypt the credentials and decrypt them in your script, but once a sufficiently determined attacker gets access to your user account and script extracting the username and password from a plain text script should not be too hard. You could use a compiled script to hide the credentials from the prying eyes, but again, it depends on how valuable access to your database is.